# Spring ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - How to use bean name for jsp view not full url with path parameters

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-annotations

My servlet-context file has

```
<beans:bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="useNotAcceptableStatusCode"
        value="false" />
    <beans:property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:map>
                            <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                        </beans:map>
                    </beans:constructor-arg>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
            <beans:bean id="jspView"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="defaultViews">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

My Controller File has

```
@Controller("resources")
public class Resources {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/resources/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public Map getResource(@PathVariable String name) {
        return new HashMap();
     }
}
```

But whenever i try to access **/server/resources/myfilename.html**

Server throws 404 saying **/server/WEB-INF/jsp/resources/myfilename.jsp** is not found. 
But it should load **/server/WEB-INF/jsp/resources.jsp** as im using BeanNameViewResolver. Please help.

Comment: Your reputation counter matches the error :-)

Comment: @Bart LOL!.I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get:

- `Controller` return a null view name, so `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator` generates one from URI = path from servlet path without slashes and filename extension: **resources/myfilename**
- `BeanNameViewResolver` try to get a `View` from context named **resources/myfilename**, seem that fails and chain to next `ViewResolver`
- `InternalResourceViewResolver` return a `JstlView` pointing to jsp prefix + viewName + suffix = **/WEB-INF/jsp/resources/myfilename.jsp**

So `BeanNameViewResolver` seems that don't resolve the view and the return of `InternalResourceViewResolver` is the expected one.

What you want (I think)

You want to remove the filename from the default view name, not only the extension.

- Implements a `RequestToViewNameTranslator` and declare it in the `DispatcherServlet` context with name **viewNameTranslator**.

For example:

```
public class StripFileNameViewNameTranslator extends DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator {

    @Override
    protected String transformPath(String lookupPath) {
        String path = super.transformPath(lookupPath);
        return  StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(path, "/");
    }
}
```